# Does relay-compiler delete unused generated files?

Tags: relayjs

My CI process, to ensure reliability of generated files, `rm -rf` all `__generated__` dirs then generates again.  It seems there is a problem (somewhere), as my results are occasionally different on OSX (local) vs Linux (CI).  I'm wondering if it is a timing problem with file events and watchman.

Then I thought, do I need to wipe out these files or will relay-compiler delete old/unused generated files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it deletes files. Here's an example from a terminal I have open:

```
Parsed default in 0.32s

Writing default
Writer time: 0.46s [0.09s compiling, 0.37s generating, 0.00s extra]
Created:
 - deleteCustomsBondMutation.graphql.js
 - putCustomsBondMutation.graphql.js
Updated:
 - BondInformationQuery.graphql.js
Deleted:
 - deleteCustomsBondMutation.graphql.js
 - putCustomsBondMutation.graphql.js
Unchanged: 5 files
Written default in 0.51s
Watching for changes to default...
```

Notice that it deleted two files. This was because I moved my mutations into a different directory.